# Is it ideal to replace django forms with django rest framework serializers in HTML terms

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to build a restful web app and I was thinking since the serializers is very similar to a django form and can be produced in the HTML. I was thinking if better use the serializers rather than the django forms

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's "better" but it can helps to keep things DRY.
I haven't done that yet but something I'm considering for my next projects.

Comment: Yeah, but this just came across my mind. Have you ever thought of solutions in cases of dynamic fields where modelformset_factory libraries is effective?

Is there a clean method on serializers the same way that the form has?

I assume that there is no commit=False in the serializers beacause I got an error when I tried one

Comment: modelformset are roughly equivalent to using many=True with serializers though I don't know if it'll work out of the box.